# Undefined reference google protocol buffer class

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

In the file I want to compile I have:

```
#include "ippacket.pb.h"
ip::PacketBuffer packet;
```

My proto file which has been compiled contains:

```
package ip;
message PacketBuffer {
```

My problem is attempting to compile, I get:
add_packet.cpp:(.text+0xc0): undefined reference to `ip::PacketBuffer::PacketBuffer()'

I don't get why the reference is undefined if I've included the header, and the header contains the class?

Comment: What compiler and flags? Make sure your actually compiling `ipacket.pb.cc` and linking protobuf: `-lprotobuf`

Comment: just g++, no extra flags. I'm a beginner so the problem may lie there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classes generated from Google protobuf are not header only so you will have compile the generated source as well. You also need to make sure that you link against the protobuf library. An example invocation of the compiler will look like:

```
g++ -Wall -o prototest main.cc ipacket.pb.cc -lprotobuf
```